# Acceptable Signal Strength Ranges for 2G/3G and 4G

Tags: 3g, 4g, network-signal, gsm

I have been logging signal strengths on my phone and am trying to understand what ranges can be considered "Good" and "Bad".

- RSSI is a measure of signal strength for GSM (2G/3G): -50dBm to
  -113dBm
- RSRP is a measure of signal strength for LTE: -44dBm to -140dBm

I understand that signal is stronger as signal strength value approaches 0. However, at what range is signal quality considered strong, moderate, weak, and poor and what these ranges mean in the real world.

E.g. At what range will calls not be possible?, At what range would calls start dropping? etc.

Is there an official resource that I can look at?

Comment: [this page in German gives you useful info](http://www.lte-anbieter.info/technik/asu.php). Call dropping, calls out of range are not dependent only on signal strength - many other factors come into play. See this [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_phone_signal)